# How do i fix this ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool() for my candlestick scanner?

Tags: python, finance

This candlestick I have made currently works for single stocks but when manipulated to multiple stocks comes up with this error

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Here is my work so far:

```
import datetime as dt 
import pandas_datareader as web
import pandas as pd

start = dt.datetime(2020,1,1)
end = dt.datetime.now()
Stock = ['ANZ.AX','APT.AX']

df = web.DataReader(Stock, 'yahoo', start, end)

# Change data to omit volume and adjusted close (can change later to display volume)
data = df[['Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close']]

for i in range(2, df.shape[0]):
    current = df.iloc[i, :]
    prev = df.iloc[i - 1, :]
    prev_2 = df.iloc[i - 2, :]

    realbody = abs(current['Open'] - current['Close'])
    candle_range = current['High'] - current['Low']

    idx = df.index[i]

    # Bullish engulfing
    df.loc[idx, 'Bullish engulfing'] = prev['Open'] > prev['Close'] and current['Close'] > current['Open'] \
    and current['High'] > prev['High'] and current['Low'] < prev['Low']

df.fillna(False, inplace=True)

pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
print(df['Bullish engulfing'])
```

Comment: What line does it occur? Have you tried the recommendation in the error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use bitwise operators (`&` for `AND` and `|` for `OR`) for boolean operations in pandas:

```
df.loc[idx, 'Bullish engulfing'] = (prev['Open'] > prev['Close']) & (current['Close'] > current['Open']) \
& (current['High'] > prev['High']) & (current['Low'] < prev['Low'])
```

Comment: I have previously tried that and the result changes from a value error to a type error. To be specfic it said "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'float' and 'float'"

Comment: The code works for me. You need to add parantheses around the conditions as well, did you try copying this snippet to your code? You got that error because you didn’t add the conditions in parantheses like I did.

Comment: Ah yes that makes sense. Now it works but some reason it only applies the pattern to the final ticker. As my result is only one column for 2 separate stocks

Comment: If the original issue is resolved, please mark the answer as accepted to close it. You can ask the issue regarding your semantics/logic in a separate question since it's different from what you originally asked.